# How to display month (as string) and year (in 4 digits) from particular date from table?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to display my date as "Jan 2017" and  "Jun 2017" from the dates 01-01-2017 and "01-06-2017"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` and `date()` function for this.

**Example:**

```
echo Date('M Y', strtotime("01-01-2017"));
echo "\n";
echo Date('M Y', strtotime("01-06-2017"));
```

**Output:**

```
Jan 2017
Jun 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use date_format() function, to directly fetch dates in required format. For your required format, you can use the following query:

```
select date_format(now(),'%b-%y');
```

Replace now() with your column name

Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) link for more details and formatting instructions